# How to write NULL values while writing a json in pyspark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a lineage using pyspark for some variables but I see json does not write null values while writing to desired path. Sample Json O/P using `df.write.format(json).save(‘to_path’)`

```
{“load”:{“employee”:{”emp_id”:”123”,”department”:”science”}}}
{“load”:{“employee”:{”emp_id”:”456”}}}
```

I don’t see `department` in second json because it is null in the source dataframe.

Update - Spark version I am using is 2.3.2 and cannot upgrade to version 3 due to organization constraints.

Comment: Why do you want to `null` fields? any requirement? by default if the field is not available it is considered as null while reading as json in spark

Comment: Actually I am trying to club delta information and sending it to other team. They would like to know if value has changed from a valid value to null as part of delta. So sending nulls are important in my case.